# Degraded performance when upgrading to CGAL-5.3

Tags: cgal

We have recently changed from CGAL-4.10, Boost1.64 to CGAL-5.3, Boost1.77, and also changing from 32 to 64 bit. We are only using the 2D geometry.

We have noticed a significant degradation in performance, possibly related to the use of the boost pool allocation.

Any helpful suggestions on where we should look to get the performance back to where it was?

Comment: See https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/6094
If you have a case showing the performance degradation it would be very useful

Comment: That sounds like it could be the problem. We are only using the Boolean set operations - - join, intersection, complement. Also is_simple_polygon.

Comment: We wound back the changes to CGAL-5.3\include\CGAL\Arr_dcel_base.h and that seems to have given a big performance improvement.

Comment: Are you also in a setting where you have a large polygon intersected with a tiny one?

Comment: Yes quite likely. Unfortunately, I don't have a simple example to give you. We noticed a significant degrade in speed and memory usage in our regression testing.